# Delete all directories/subs/files, 24 hours old... but not root - PHP

Tags: php, file, timestamp

[image: Folders]
I needed to delete all files, subdirectories, and root directories that is older than 24hr!

Just 25-10-2018, only this directory should remain!

```
public static function wufppClearDir($dir)
{
    $hours = 86400; //24h
    $files = glob(preg_replace('/(\*|\?|\[)/', '[$1]', $dir) . '/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file == $dir . '/.' or $file == $dir . '/..' or (time() - filemtime($file)) < $hours) {
            continue;
        }
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            self::wufppClearDir($file);

        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    if ($dir !== wp_upload_dir()["basedir"] . "/wufpp/temp/") {
        if ((time() - filemtime($dir)) >= $hours) {
            rmdir($dir);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your problem/question?  Does your code work or is it deleting things it shouldn't?

Comment: `filemtime` is the last time the file was modified, not when it was created. so if there is even 1 file in those folders that was modified in the last 24 hours they would remain  (of course filectime, does the same thing on Linux)  But if you are naming the folder based on the date, why not just use that, instead. (probably a time stamp would be easier to work with though)